# how to send encrypted message via nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, smtp

I am sending emails via **postfix** mail server.
the code is on **node.js** using **sendmail**:

```
   const sendmail = require('sendmail')({
    logger: {
      debug: console.log,
      info: console.info,
      warn: console.warn,
      error: console.error
    },
    silent: true,
    smtpPort: 25, // Default: 25
      dkim: {
        privateKey: fs.readFileSync('mail_key.txt', 'utf8'),
        keySelector: 'mail'
      },
    smtpHost: 'mail.mydomain.com' // Default: -1 - extra smtp host after resolveMX
  })


const text = 'some text .... ';
  var mes=sendmail({
     from: ' "some sender" <info@mydomain.com',
     to: data.Email,
     subject: 'Your Account Data',
     html:text,
   }, function(err, reply) {
     console.log(err && err.stack);
     console.dir(reply);
   });
```

messages are send successfully. but still is encrypted. 
i want to know how to send emails to be encrypted.
BTW my connection is encrypted using TLS‌ before. I want to encrypt message content.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) package to encrypt your string value and here is how you can use it:

```
  let text2 = 'some....';
  bcrypt.hash(text2, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if(err) throw err; 
    text = hash;
    console.log('happy hashing',text);
});
```

Comment: thanks, but your solution only encrypts the the message string. and if i send this the message text will be received encrypted. I wanna sth like s/mime...